# Is iOS's workspace same with android's project?

Tags: android, ios

Is Android's 'Project' the same as iOS's 'Workspace' ???
And is 'Module: app' of Android the same as 'target' of iOS ???

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't try to compare these two. Learn them as two separate concepts.

Comment: OK , Thank you !